# Material UI Autocomplete how to cancel the chosen option

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, keyboard, material-ui

Can anybody help me?

After surfing options with pressing up/down keys, I can't cancel the chosen option. Maybe anybody knows where the chosen option stored and how can I get access to it?

To be clear - I'm trying to use autocomplete without the mouse and once I turn to option selection with pressing arrow down I can`t go back with no option chosen. Thx

Comment: It's not clear to me

Comment: As per my usage, the input field remains in focus while you were moving items through keyboard up/down. can you tell me the variant you are using ?
In extreme case it could happen that you need to use tab or shift-tab to bring the focus on the input field

Comment: Sorry, fixed the problem explanation

Comment: You can use `escape` key to close options selection picker without choosing any options

Comment: But still, do you know how to get access to the selected option or where it stored?